# Calling a java Method in c++ class in qt

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I want to check whether Android Wifi is On or Not in my C++ code. I have written a small java function for this. Below is my java class code

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.content.Context;

public class CheckWifiConnectivity {

 public static boolean  wificonnected(Context ctx) {

     ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

     if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
         return true;
     }
         return false;
  }

}
```

But i am not able to call it in my C++ class. can anybody help me that how can i call it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing java file in qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760599/executing-java-file-in-qt)